# When does a node.js process die accidentally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, process

I have a node.js + express web application and I see that in production it is recommended to have a process manager in case your node.js process dies.

My question is: is there something in your code that can accidentally kill it, or is it only the external factors that can kill it ?

Apparently, I had the wrong notion that an error in JS will kill the node process, but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that can cause your node process to die. For example it could run out of memory, it could crash from a JS error, etc.

In production you would likely want your node process to restart after a crash, but you should still look to see why it is crashing and correct your issue.

--EDIT-- asked for JS crash example

The most common crash I find from a JS crash is the code in a db error that was never tested. Let's assume my_obj doesn't exist. It won't crash until it hits that line.

```
db.query(..., function(err, results){
    if(err){
        console.log("OH NO THERE WAS AN ERROR LOOKING UP " + my_obj);
    } else {
        //handle success
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of JS code that will generate an error that will kill the process ?